# Excel: Updating a column searched with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

I have an inventory worksheet (Excel) with tens of columns (product's features) and few hundred rows (products). First few columns are Sticker number (each product has it's own Sticker number), Status, Arrival Date and so on.

To be able to check easily the Status of multiple products at the same time, I have made another sheet using VLOOKUP. On that sheet I can give a Sticker number and it searches and shows this product's Status using a basic VLOOKUP function. By inputting more Sticker numbers I can see more Statuses. Usually these Statuses vary quite a lot.

Problem comes when I want to change all these listed Statuses to a new certain Status, which I could enter f.e. to cell B2. I mean updating the Status only for the products I have listed on this VLOOKUP sheet. How can I do this?

Comment: Would you post your `VLookup` formula?

Comment: IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3;Kesken!A10:C999;3;FALSE);"unknown product")

It is a very basic lookup. I can see the Status with this but I can't replace it to the original cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lookup formula only looks up values. If you want to process the results that are returned then you would need VBA to loop through the results, find their respective counterpart on the source sheet and make the changes.

An alternative could be to go to the source sheet and use filters to show only the desired rows. Then you can quickly select all visible cells, enter a new value, confirm with Ctrl-Enter to change them all at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. By using filters this is quite hard to get working if I understand those correctly - each product has it's unique sticker number so I would need to be able to set a filter with multiple values. Is there a way to do this easily? I can use a barcode scanner and scan those sticker numbers very easily but I don't know if I can make this list of sticker numbers to work as a filter somehow.

Comment: If your data is in an Excel Table object or you have the Autofilter button enabled, then you should see the filter drop-downs in the column headers. You can select multiple items in the filter drop downs. Or, if you have a list of values in a range, you can use the Advanced Filter to filter the list in place. Look up these topics in the Help.

Comment: Yes, I can see the drop-down and search by selecting sticker numbers manually there - but as I want to select multiple items, this isn't very handy. I can read those numbers to a list which should work as a criteria for filtering. Tried Advanced Filter but didn't yet succeed with it.

Comment: I recorded a macro which can select the items listed:
`Range("Table1[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange _:=Range("Kesken!Criteria"), Unique:=False`
I would now like to update column 3, starting from cell C10 automatically with value of cell C1. I want to update only visible cells. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Select the visible cells, type the new value in the active cell, hold down Ctrl and hit Enter.

Comment: I understand that but it isn't automated. As I save the macro to run with a hotkey I would like the macro also to change the visible cells on column C.

Comment: If you use code, you don't need to filter anything. The code can just loop through your data and write the new value into the rows that meet the criteria. Don't overthink this. I think by now you are asking a different question. Close this one and start a new question about the code you need.

Comment: In my opinion it's the same question still, changing a columns value in specified rows. I did manage to do this with code finally however horrible the code is. Thank you for the replies.